# Python: Replace None with multiple different values

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I would like to replace all `None` of a certain pd.DataFrame column with different values.
According to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html this is possible using lists.

I tried using the following [1]:

```
df["column_name"].replace(to_replace=[None, None], value= ["Peter", "Mike"], inplace=True)
```

However this changes every `None` to "Mike". It seems to ignore or overwrite "Peter".
Therefore, I tried the following [2]:

```
replacement = ["Peter", "Mike"]
df["column_name"].replace(to_replace=[None for i in range(len(replacement))], value=[i for i in replacement], inplace=True)
```

But this does yield the same result as [1].

Important: The length of the list `replacement` is always equal to the number of `None` that appear in the respective pd.DataFrame column.

Does anyone see what I am missing here?

Thank you!

---

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column_name": ["Anna", None, "Simon", None],
                   "Department": ["Finance", "IT", "HR", "Finance"], 
                   "Age":[34, 23, 56,32]})
```

Comment: kindly share some sample data, with expected output. data, not pics.

Answer (score 0):

Naive solution:

```py
name_list = ['Peter', 'Mike']
for n, name in enumerate(df['column_name'].values):
     if not name:
         df.at[n, 'column_name'] = name_list.pop()
print(df)
```

results in:

```py
  column_name Department  Age
0        Anna    Finance   34
1        Mike         IT   23
2       Simon         HR   56
3       Peter    Finance   32
```